# Div behind the div

Tags: html, css

I need #slides_ribbon_left and #slides_ribbon_right to put behind the #frame. I am wonder why z-indexes don't help! Here is the link - http://layot.prestatrend.com/
Could anybody help please?

Comment: You could find them at red ribbon under the slider.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#slides has z-index: 100 and #frame z-index: 0 and they're sibblings so any child elements of #slide will be above #frame. As far as I can see you'll need to change some html as well. The following link may help too: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Understanding_CSS_z-index/The_stacking_context

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a relative, fixed, or absolute position on elements for z-index to take effect.

Just add `position: relative` to each element (or fixed or absolute, depending on what you want).

Comment: If I'm going to use `z-index` usually start my css reset with something like `* { position: relative; }`...

Comment: I know about these positions and I already have them but it is does not help! OMG

Comment: @elclanrs, you reset every element to position relative, just to use z-index!?  That seems like a bit of overkill....

Comment: **@thgescientist** it all depends on your needs. Is not any more overkill that any other quick reset like `* { margin: 0; }`. A post about this exact topic http://css-tricks.com/what-if-there-was-no-position-static/